# how to click on an element in a different tab using js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So in a chrome extension.

- when the user clicks a button
- send a message to background
- open a new popup window
- in the new window, click on the specific element

I can get most of the way but fail to be able to focus in on the necessary document for the js to get the element ID on.

content.js

```
user_clicked_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['xyz'], (result) => {

        if (result.xyz['u'].includes('123') && result.xyz['da'] !== 'cool') {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
                {
                    s: 'quick',
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
    if (request.s === 'quick') {
        chrome.windows.create({
            url: './options.html', type: "popup", focused: true
        },
            () => {
                let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
                chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions, function (tabs) {
                    tabs[0].document.getElementById("element_of_interest").click()
                });
            }    
        );
    }
});
```

the issue could be summarized as, how do I get the "document" of a different tab? (**assuming I own the 'different tab'**)

Comment: you don't have permission to access to document of another tab its not possible

Comment: Your right in most cases, however the new document is one from within the chrome extension so might try and make a workaround for this case. (or is that still impossible>)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was to add message passing the whole way to the element of interest and have it click itself.

The result looks like this and behaves as desired.

content.js

```
user_clicked_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['xyz'], (result) => {

        if (result.xyz['u'].includes('123') && result.xyz['da'] !== 'cool') {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
                {
                    s: 'quick',
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
    if (request.s === 'quick') {
        chrome.windows.create({
            url: './options.html', type: "popup", focused: true
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("send message to options page")
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
                    {
                        s: 'quick_click',
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
             
        });
    }
});
```

in the options.html file, the desired element is a react element, so I was able to add a listener in the componentDidMount function

options/index.js

```
   componentDidMount() {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
            if (request.s === 'quick_click') {
                this.handleClick()
            }
        });
    }
```